# How to get data from inside document in firestore

Tags: flutter, dart

i am getting data from inside Doucument in firestor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpMhe.png)

Comment: Please include your code as part of the question. Not as a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

your code isn't clear but if your `questionSnapShot` is a `DocumentSnapshot` you can retrieve the data whiteout adding `.data()`, so just remove `.data()` if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

If I‘d have to guess, I‘d say that you have a problem with null safety.

You can check beforhand if `.data()` is null or just add !

```
questionSnapshotData = questionSnapshot.data()!["question1"];
```

https://dart.dev/null-safety